# unable to install 'rasa_nlu' by terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, rasa-nlu, rasa, anaconda3

I am trying to install 'rasa_nlu' by the terminal using this command:

```
pip install rasa_nlu
```

but it shows this error that I don't know how to resolve it:

```
Collecting rasa_nlu
  Using cached rasa_nlu-0.15.1-py3-none-any.whl (147 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: boto3~=1.9 in ./opt/anaconda3/envs/allProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from rasa_nlu) (1.16.47)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm~=4.19 in ./opt/anaconda3/envs/allProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from rasa_nlu) (4.50.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16 in ./opt/anaconda3/envs/allProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from rasa_nlu) (1.18.5)
Requirement already satisfied: requests~=2.20 in ./opt/anaconda3/envs/allProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from rasa_nlu) (2.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: s3transfer<0.4.0,>=0.3.0 in ./opt/anaconda3/envs/allProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from boto3~=1.9->rasa_nlu) (0.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 in ./opt/anaconda3/envs/allProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from boto3~=1.9->rasa_nlu) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: botocore<1.20.0,>=1.19.47 in ./opt/anaconda3/envs/allProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from boto3~=1.9->rasa_nlu) (1.19.47)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.25.4 in ./opt/anaconda3/envs/allProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from botocore<1.20.0,>=1.19.47->boto3~=1.9->rasa_nlu) (1.26.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 in ./opt/anaconda3/envs/allProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from botocore<1.20.0,>=1.19.47->boto3~=1.9->rasa_nlu) (2.8.1)
Collecting cloudpickle~=0.6.1
  Using cached cloudpickle-0.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting coloredlogs~=10.0
  Using cached coloredlogs-10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (47 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: humanfriendly>=4.7 in ./opt/anaconda3/envs/allProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from coloredlogs~=10.0->rasa_nlu) (9.1)
Collecting future~=0.17.1
  Using cached future-0.17.1.tar.gz (829 kB)
Collecting gevent~=1.3
  Using cached gevent-1.5.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (1.8 MB)
Collecting greenlet>=0.4.14
  Using cached greenlet-0.4.17.tar.gz (61 kB)
Collecting jsonschema~=2.6
  Using cached jsonschema-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting klein~=17.10
  Using cached klein-17.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (30 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug in ./opt/anaconda3/envs/allProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from klein~=17.10->rasa_nlu) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in ./opt/anaconda3/envs/allProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from klein~=17.10->rasa_nlu) (1.15.0)
Collecting matplotlib~=2.2
  Using cached matplotlib-2.2.5.tar.gz (36.7 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/zahraaal-nemer/opt/anaconda3/envs/allProjects/venv/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/sm/bjkmpsf90ng76c26v82cg1j80000gn/T/pip-install-w584fd2l/matplotlib_052328d9a48d4df5b2eccca54a9fc129/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/sm/bjkmpsf90ng76c26v82cg1j80000gn/T/pip-install-w584fd2l/matplotlib_052328d9a48d4df5b2eccca54a9fc129/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/sm/bjkmpsf90ng76c26v82cg1j80000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-t9qjhxas
         cwd: /private/var/folders/sm/bjkmpsf90ng76c26v82cg1j80000gn/T/pip-install-w584fd2l/matplotlib_052328d9a48d4df5b2eccca54a9fc129/
    Complete output (106 lines):
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
    ============================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options
    
    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                matplotlib: yes [2.2.5]
                    python: yes [3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 02:22:02)  [Clang
                            10.0.0 ]]
                  platform: yes [darwin]
    
    REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                     numpy: yes [version 1.18.5]
          install_requires: yes [handled by setuptools]
                    libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                            be found. Using local copy.]
                  freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype2 (ft2build.h)
                            could not be found.  You may need to install the
                            development package.]
                       png: no  [pkg-config information for 'libpng' could not
                            be found.]
                     qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'libqhull' could not
                            be found. Using local copy.]
    
    OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
               sample_data: yes [installing]
                  toolkits: yes [installing]
                     tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
            toolkits_tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
    
    OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                    macosx: yes [installing, darwin]
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
                    qt5agg: no  [PySide2 not found; PyQt5 not found]
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
                    qt4agg: no  [PySide not found; PyQt4 not found]
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
                   gtk3agg: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
                 gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairocffi or pycairo to be installed.]
                    gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
                     tkagg: yes [installing; run-time loading from Python Tcl /
                            Tk]
                     wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                       gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
                       agg: yes [installing]
                     cairo: no  [cairocffi or pycairo not found]
                 windowing: no  [Microsoft Windows only]
    
    OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                    dvipng: no
               ghostscript: no
                     latex: no
                   pdftops: no
    
    OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
                      dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]
    
    ============================================================================
                            * The following required packages can not be built:
                            * freetype, png
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

can anyone help me in resolving that? I am trying for 3 days till now and I could not find any solution as I am a beginner in using rasa and python and need guidance

Also, I am using the MacOSX and Anaconda3

Answer (score 0):

You can download the `rasa_nlu wheel file` from [here](https://pypi.org/project/rasa-nlu/#files).

Then use `pip install path/rasa_nlu-0.15.1-py3-none-any.whl` to install.

Comment: still the same error with that started from ` ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:`   to this line `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.` is desplayed for me